# PHP round() -0.000000001 results in -0

Tags: php, rounding, zero

I think it's known that rounding a very small negative number will give -0 as output.
Is there a smart way to change that in postive zero?
Now I have fixed it like:

```
if (round($number)== "-0") { echo "0";} 
else { echo round($number); }
```

But there may be a better way?

Thank you!

Comment: `intval` is *a* way. Not sure it's a *smart* way. Be aware that a rounded floating point number may not fit in an integer number though so you might end up with overflows

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php

Comment: Thank you @apokryfos, that does work in my case. The max is 10, so no problem with overflows. I will have a problem when I want one decimal, but I will find a solution at that time. Thanks again!